# Docker for local PHP development: override $_SERVER vars

Tags: php, docker, apache, localhost

I am using Docker for local PHP development. Can I override `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` with a custom string? Both contain now **localhost**, but some part of my code depends on this vars being filled with the actual domain. I tried to set the `hostname`in `docker-compose.yaml`, but that did not work. The container's webserver is Apache. PS. I would prefer not to use any browser plugin to change the DNS lookup on my DEV machine.

Comment: Have you added the hostname to the local hosts file (/etc/hosts on linux) to help resolve the new hostname.

Comment: @Nigel Ren: Do you mean /etc/hosts on the host machine or inside the container?

Comment: The host machine.

Comment: @Nigel Ren: No, I didn't try, as I need a solution that doesn't require any setup on my host maschine. If possible, I would like to specify the host in the Dockerfile, in docker-compose.yaml or in any config file that is copied when the container is built.

Comment: This is only for development purposes, once the real hostname is registered, the DNS will resolve it.